# Every 15 minut appears a blue screen Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Every 15 minutes a blue screen appears and gives such errors IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL or IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, file netio.sys Or KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE This started to happen after changing the thermal compound Help fix the problem Windows 10

Comment: You need to give us a little bit more to work with: brand, model of your PC? Desktop or laptop? Aside from affixing new thermal paste (?), did you do anything else on this PC?

Comment: @Didier , i built it myself , i reseted BIOS and all

Comment: OK. When? Has it always been misbehaving like this, like, you built it over the weekend and are taking it on its maiden voyage, or have you had it for some time and suddently it started throwing tantrums? @John is right about it probably being a case of bad driver(s), because that's what the error codes you gave us usually indicate. Still, recent Windows updates have caused isues like this too, and sometimes, uninstalling recent updates and/or restoring your system to a date prior to the updates can solve the issue entirely. It has for me a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

That is usually a driver problem, but can be hardware.

(1) Open the computer case, remove the CPU and / or GPU and replace the thermal compound with a thin, complete layer of top quality thermal compound (arctic silver or comparable).

(2) Update BIOS, and all other drivers.

Restart finally at the end and test.

Comment: I have reseted a BIOS , can it be cause of this problem?

Comment: Also update all your drivers. BIOS is one possible cause. More likely the drivers doing this.